# Django Haystack Solr facets.fields disappearing

Tags: python, django, solr

As I am rebuilding (rebuild_index), the field names returned from facets.fields begin to disappear as though they are being overwritten.  For instance... if the facets.fields was displaying a list of (a, b, c, d) on the first update, it will then display (a, b, c) on the second and eventually the list will be half complete.

I could generate a list of values outside of using the facets.fields but I would think this wouldn't be necessary and I'm overlooking something simple.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

schema.xml

```
<field name="models" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" />
<field name="models_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" />
```

search_indexes.py

```
models = indexes.MultiValueField(faceted=True)

def prepare_models(self, obj):
    return [g for g in obj.model.all()]
```

*_text.txt

```
{% for model in object.model.all %}
    {{ model|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

template.html

```
{% if facets.fields.models %}
    <form name="drilldown_models" action="{% url 'cmaster:search' %}" method="GET">
        <span class="faceting-title">Models</span>
        <select name="selected_facets">
        {% for model in facets.fields.models %}
            {% if model.1 > 0 %}
                <option value="models_exact:{{ model.0 }}">{{ model.0 }} : {{ model.1 }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
        {% for fac in selected_facets %}
            <input type="hidden" name="selected_facets" value="{{ fac }}">
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="hidden" name="q" value="{{ query }}">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
{% else %}
    <p>No model facets.</p>
{% endif %}
```

tldr; refreshing my templated page during a rebuild_index shows facet fields disappearing.

** Update

The list was a few items over 100.  Faceting will only show the first 100 results unless adding a 'limit' argument.  In my case, 'limit=-1' for all results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list was a few items over 100. Faceting will only show the first 100 results unless adding a 'limit' argument. In my case, 'limit=-1' for all results.